# How to use Backbone (*underscore) templates with Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, templates, backbone.js, flask

I need to use Backbone templates with my Flask backend system.I already have Flask templates, routes, HTTP-methods for login etc.

How can I use backbone templating system with existing flask views instead of Jinja2 ?

Here some examples

```
@app.route('/') #I have login page here!
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET']) #When i clickin SUBMIT - I     redirecting here and do stuff
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
#code </code>
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking. Is it that on the page generated by your flask templates you want to use backbone.js to manage some parts of that page? E.g. Do you want to havev a backbone view `LoginView` that handles the login?

Comment: sorry if it is unclear.
I want to use Backbone templates INSTEAD of Jinja2 templates.

And yes, You absolutely right - i need to have Backbone.View, used with Flask...

Comment: Jinja2 generates HTML on the server. Backbone runs in the client's browser, commonly managing a single page app. With backbone I often start with a static HTML page and retrieve my Models through a REST api on the server. Switching all Jinja2 templates to use Backbone's dependency Underscore.js (which contains some templating functions) for templating would mean that you'd have to restructure your app quite a bit. Could you show some of the code that you have tried and how that is not working as you expect?

Comment: Thank you! Your answer pushed me to think twice how to use such things!
Now i solve my problems!